# How can I add a new column in my data table using dplyr function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data table with all the data related to Bank Customers.

I want to create another data table (labelled as `BankCustomerAgeCategorized`) with a new column added to it where the data is grouped based on the `Age` column in the original table.

I am using a tutorial online and after running the code provided by them, I get an error. The person is able to run the code as shown in the tutorial but I get this error. Please advise why this is happening?

```
BankCustomerAgeCategorized <- transform(BankCustomer, 
Generation = 
if_else(Age<22, "Z", 
if_else(Age<41, "Y", 
if_else(Age<53, "X", 
Baby Boomers""))))
```

Output -

```
Error: unexpected symbol in 
"BankCustomerAgeCategorized <- transform(BankCustomer, 
Generation = if_else(Age<22, "Z", 
if_else(Age<41, "Y", 
if_else(Age<53, "X", 
Baby Boomers"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Baby Boomers"` in the last `if_else()` should be in quotation marks ("") but is currently outside them.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! I am new to coding and precisely even after 2 hours and trying numerous functions, I was still not able to figure it out. Thanks for helping me! I feel so disappointed with myself.

Comment: It's totally normal!! If you aren't using a code editor or development environment (like Rstudio) it can be helpful to get one (usually an app) because they can help you spot errors like this and highlight text in different colors that make it easier to read!

Comment: I use RStudio but still I was not able to locate it.

Answer (score 2):

This is for demonstration purposes only:

If you want to use `dplyr` package: Here is an alternative way with `mutate` and `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

BankCustomerAgeCategorized <- BankCustomer %>% 
  mutate(Generation = case_when(Age < 22 ~ "Z", 
                                Age < 41 ~ "Y", 
                                Age < 53 ~ "X", 
                                TRUE ~ "Baby Boomers"))
```

Comment: I actually tried using this based on examples online but it was returning me an error. Also, could you please tell me why you used %>% in your code?